When scrolling to bottom of scroll view and pressing a button within the scroll view crashes app
I have a Scroll View with some elements including a button at the bottom of the scroll view.
When I don't scroll all the way to the bottom and press the button the code works, but when i scroll to the end of the scroll view and press the button the app crashes.
This is the structure:
<View
    style={{flex:1,}} >
    <ScrollView
       removeClippedSubviews={true}
       overScrollMode="never"
       showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
       style={{padding:10,}}   
       refreshControl={<RefreshControl refreshing={refresh} onRefresh={onRefresh}/>}>
   
        <SomeElements/>
        <SomeElements/>
        
        <View style={styles.contentContainer}>
            <SomeElements/>
            <SomeElements/>
            <SomeElements/>

            <RadioGroup 
                radioButtons={radioData} 
                selectedId={selectedId}
                onPress={setSelectedId}
                containerStyle={{justifyContent:'flex-start', display:'flex',alignItems:'flex-start'}}
                        />
            <Button onPress={onChat} title="COMMENT ON THE POLL"></Button> <--crashes when scrolled to bottom and button clicked
       </View>
    </ScrollView>
</View>

The crash seems to happen when there are more than two radio button in the scroll view.
I even added the button to the header when the scroll view is not at bottom the comment button works, but when scroll view is at bottom and I press the comment button in the header the app crashes.

<ScrollView
    overScrollMode="never"
    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
    style={{ padding: 10 }}
    refreshControl={<RefreshControl refreshing={refresh} onRefresh={onRefresh} />}
>
    <SomeElements />
    <SomeElements />
    
    <View style={styles.contentContainer}>
        <SomeElements />
        <SomeElements />
        <SomeElements />
        <Button onPress={onChat} title="COMMENT ON THE POLL"></Button>
    </View>
</ScrollView>


still crashes when I take out removeClippedSubviews={true}

Then may be it's a problem of ScrollView check with debug and try this code as well
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
<ScrollView
overScrollMode="never"
showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
style={{ padding: 10 }}
refreshControl={}

<SomeElements />
<SomeElements />

<View style={styles.contentContainer}>
  <SomeElements />
  <SomeElements />
  <SomeElements />
  <Button onPress={onChat} title="COMMENT ON THE POLL" />
</View>



Can you also check your ScrollView import. I have many times gotten stuck where I imported from a library such as gestures.

it is using react-native-gesture-handler but when i switched Scroll View to react-native package it still crashed.
